# Modify z-index of AG-grid cell's tooltip

Tags: css, highcharts, tooltip, ag-grid, z-index

I have created a HighChart in a Ag data grid cell. On hovering over the Line chart, I need to display a tooltip with few details. I am able to show the tooltip within the cell, but as the tooltip is displayed within the cell, the content gets hidden in the cell. I need to  display the tooltip in such a way that it can overlap and display the tooltip over another cell.

I tried setting the z-index to 99999 & position as relative/absolute of highchart tooltip. But it does not reflect.

Tried to override the css class .highcharts-tooltip by adding z index

Please can some css expert help me identify the issue?

Comment: please provide a fiddle with a working example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to modify the CSS of the highchart tooltip.I followed the properties used in the below URL & it worked for me:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline

I had missed out adding below chart options:

```
tooltip: {
      outside: true,
}
plotOptions: {
      series: {
        animation: false,
        lineWidth: 1,
        shadow: false,
        states: {
          hover: {
            lineWidth: 1
          }
        },
        marker: {
          radius: 1,
          states: {
            hover: {
              radius: 2
            }
          }
        },
        fillOpacity: 0.25
      }
    }
```